# Do American natives pronounce t of at in "at any ..." as FLAP T?

Tags: pronunciation

According to the American Accent rules, any T is pronounced as FLAP T when it comes in between two vowels that may be in a word or in between two words like "at any"....

So, Do American natives pronounce t of at in "at any ..." as FLAP T or Pure T ?

Comment: Yes, generally, between vowels American English neutralizes /d/ and /t/ and flaps them both. This is most prominent when the first vowel is stressed, like _better, water, ladder, motor, written,_ etc. But it can certainly happen between unstressed vowels, like _at a corner, automation_; and also before stressed vowels like _redacted, gradation_. But that's in rapid speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler so, will I be correct to pronounce T of at in "at any" or "at all" as FLAP T ?

Comment: I have no idea whether you will be correct because I can't hear you. And I'm not sure you mean [ɾ] when you say "FLAP T"; it's voiced and it could just as easily be called "FLAP D". But if you listen to Americans, you'll hear /ə'ɾɔl/ for _at all_, unless the speakers are from West Coast, where /ɔ/ and /a/ are not distinguished.

Comment: Yes, the t of "at all" flaps, because it's at the end of a syllable (as well as being intervocalic), and it's at the end of a syllable, because "at" is a word of English.  Likewise, e.g., in "a parrot of mine".  The alternative would be to resyllabify to put t at the beginning of the following syllable, "I don't care for this a tall", sometimes called "linking", and heard in some British speech.

Comment: And some pronounce It as a glottal stop.  I think I pronounce It in all these ways under different circumstances.

Comment: You should join the Writers.SE community. You have some very good answers posted on your question https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/47672/how-to-differentiate-between-two-people-with-the-same-name-in-a-story.